# my setCloseoperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); is receiving a error EXIT_ON_CLOSE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, swing

package dragon.io.display;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

private frame;

private String title;
private int width, height;

public Display(String title, int width, int height){
    this.title = title;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    creatDisplay();

}

private void creatDisplay(){
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setlocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

here is my code i watched a tutorial and he had this exact code but no errors

Comment: You got suggestions from your posting yesterday  and have NOT changed the code you posted here!!! What is the point of us making suggestions if you don't change the code???

Comment: i tried to change it cause i already had this ready yesterday but forgot to change it back to "private frame JFrame;" sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> he had this exact code but no errors

I doubt it. There are multiple errors:

```
private frame;
```

That is not a statement. What type of object do you want "frame" to be?  You defined the "title" variable correctly. The same rules apply for a JFrame.

```
frame.setlocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Java methods and variables are case sensitive. That is not the proper spelling of the method. Read the `JFrame` API for the proper spelling of the method.

> i watched a tutorial

Instead of watching a tutorial, read a tutorial.

Then you can actually copy/paste code and not make typing errors.

For example start with the `FrameDemo` found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). The code is better structured because it also shows how to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).